# angular2-systemJS path not working

Tags: javascript, path, angular, systemjs

I am using this angular2 project in which I have used [ng2Draggable](https://github.com/CoderAjay/ng2Draggable) npm package.
After Successful installation,I have configured project using systemjs as below:

```
<script>
    System.config({        
    paths:{           
        'ng2-dnd'         : '../node_modules/ng2-dnd/bundles/ng2-dnd.js'           
    },
    packages: {            
      app: {
        format: 'register',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      }         
    }
  });

 System.import('app/main')
       .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
</script>
```

And in my **app.component.ts** i have written:

```
import { Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {DND_PROVIDERS, DND_DIRECTIVES} from 'ng2-dnd/ng2-dnd';

@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    templateUrl: "app/app.component.html",
    providers: [],
    directives: [DND_DIRECTIVES]
})


export class AppComponent {      
    constructor() {                
    }  
    ngOnInit() {

    }
}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<h4>Simple Drag-and-Drop</h4>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <div class="panel panel-success">
            <div class="panel-heading">Available to drag</div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="panel panel-default" dnd-draggable [dragEnabled]="true">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <div>Drag Me</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <div dnd-droppable class="panel panel-info">
            <div class="panel-heading">Place to drop</div>
            <div class="panel-body">
            </div>
       </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-3">
       <div dnd-droppable class="panel panel-warning">
           <div class="panel-heading">Restricted to drop</div>
           <div class="panel-body">
           </div>
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

But when I am trying to run the project its showing me this error:

```
GET http://localhost:3208/src/ng2-dnd/ng2-dnd 404 (Not Found)
Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:3208/src/ng2-dnd/ng2-dnd(…)
```

my project structure :
[image: project structure]

any suggestions?
thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you provide the structure of your project? Thanks!

Comment: @ThierryTemplier posted an image for my project structure

Comment: In your browser dev tools, what is the value of `System._loader.modules`?  When I load `ng2-dnd` using a script tag, I see 'http://localhsot:5000/ng2-dnd' along with entries like 'http://localhost:5000/src/dnd.component' for also 'dnd.config', 'dnd.draggable', etc.  Maybe in your config try to map `ng2-dnd` to `/`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done a lot of looking and I think I found the way to note bundles in the SystemJS config.  Try adding this to your config:

```
bundles: {
    '../node_modules/ng2-dnd/bundles/ng2-dnd.js': ['/ng2-dnd/*']
}
```

`bundles` is the opposite of the other config settings, the bundle is the key and a list of modules (or paths with wildcards it seems) that are inside the bundle.  When anything in the list on the right is imported, SystemJS just makes sure the bundle is loaded and run first, since it should register it's own paths.  If this doesn't work, look in your 'network' tab of dev tools and see what is getting requested.  If you cannot get to `ng2-dnd.js` using your browser, then SystemJS can't either.  You can try the cdn also:

```
bundles: {
    'https://npmcdn.com/ng2-dnd@1.6.5/bundles/ng2-dnd.js': ['/ng2-dnd/*']
}
```

If you are still getting requests to urls like './src' in your browser debug network tab or 404 errors for them, then the module is most likely just broken.  You could try adding something saying those paths are provided by the bundle in the value above:

```
['/ng2-dnd/*', '/src/*']
```

I tried out several different module loading strategies with rxjs and created a [github repo](https://npmcdn.com/ng2-dnd@1.6.5/ng2-dnd) if you're interested in checking it out.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a package entry:

```
packages: {            
  app: {
    format: 'register',
    defaultExtension: 'js'
  },
  'ng2-dnd' : {defaultExtension : 'js' }   
}
```

That should let the application look at the correct path.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the `map` attribute instead in your SystemJS configuration:

```
System.config({        
  map: {           
    'ng2-dnd': '../node_modules/ng2-dnd/bundles/ng2-dnd.js'           
  },
  (...)
});
```

That said, since you want to use a bundled JS file, you could include it directly in a script element:

```
<script src="../node_modules/ng2-dnd/bundles/ng2-dnd.js"></script>
```

Comment: tried this ..now error message is:`system.src.js:1154 GET http://localhost:3208/node_modules/ng2-dnd/bundles/ng2-dnd.js/ng2-dnd`

Comment: its still not working even if i tried configuring paths and other things

Comment: I think that the script approach is the correct one. Do you try it? If so do you have some errors?

Comment: Is there any way to use Import instead of a script tag though?   I have never gotten that to work with bundles.  It would be nice to get that first page load and let the scripts be imported in the background by SystemJS, but mapping a package like you show has never worked for me.

Comment: @ThierryTemplier I tried the script approach.its showing following errors: `GET http://localhost:3208/src/@angular/core 404 (Not Found)GET http://localhost:3208/src/@angular/common/src/facade/lang 404 (Not Found) GET http://localhost:3208/src/ng2-dnd/ng2-dnd 404 (Not Found)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a bundle, you shouldn't need an entry in your SystemJS config.  Copy the bundle to your distribution directory and use a `<script>` tag to load it before SystemJS.  I think the problem is that the node module is not configured correctly.  Your import should be like this:

```
import {DND_PROVIDERS, DND_DIRECTIVES} from 'ng2-dnd'; // no trailing /ng2-dnd
```

The problem is that they didn't provide an 'index.ts'.  If you copy `ng2-dnd.ts` to `index.ts` in `node_modules/ng2-dnd` then your code will compile without the `/ng2-dnd` at the end, and because you're using the bundle SystemJS will know that the module already exists.  SystemJS is looking for a class 'ng2-dnd' in the module 'ng2-dnd' and that doesn't exist.

Also, it looks like your web server is serving out of a sibling directory of node_modules, is that right?  There's no way then that you'll be able to use '..' to get up past the root of the directory you're serving.  You'll have to copy the bundle to your distribution directory.  SystemJS works on the client, so if you can't get to it with your browser, SystemJS can't either.

Comment: yes , my webserver  is serving out of a sibling directory of node_modules,but my other node_modules are getting imported correctly.

Comment: I also tried doing `<script src="/node_modules/ng2-dnd/bundles/ng2-dnd.js"></script>` and omitting systemjs configuration it didnt work either.

Comment: What error do you get with the script tag?  Can you get to that url in your browser?  If the script loads, you should be able to use it by removing any references to it in your system js config if you change your typescript to just use 'ng2-dnd' instead of 'ng2-dnd/ng2-dnd', I tried it out.

Comment: i did what you said, i am getting below errors: `GET localhost:3208/src/@angular/core 404 (Not Found)GET localhost:3208/src/@angular/common/src/facade/lang 404 (Not Found) GET localhost:3208/src/ng2-dnd/ng2-dnd 404 (Not Found) `

Answer (score 0):

I'm using "ng2-dnd".
This is my config in "systemjs-config.js".

```
System.config({
    map: {
        'ng2-dnd': 'node_modules/ng2-dnd'
    },
    packages: {
        'ng2-dnd':  { main: 'index.js',  defaultExtension: 'js' },
    }
});
```

Do not forget:

- Import DND_PROVIDERS, DND_DIRECTIVES from ng2-dnd.
- Use DND_PROVIDERS in the providers property of your application
  component.
- Add DND_DIRECTIVES to the directives property of your application
  component.
  For more details: https://github.com/akserg/ng2-dnd